# Trying to implement text-based Hangman game in Java

Tags: java

I need to check if the user-input letter, along with the spaces they guess, is at a specific spot on the hidden word.

the variable one is equal to the space index the user guessed.. and letterGuess is the letter they guessed. How is my code wrong??

example: secret word is hello

```
hidden word is ==  -----
```

user guesses `h 0 1 2 3`
so, it needs to check if the spaces at indexes 0 1 2 3 at the word `hello` contain the user guessed "h"
if so, need to replace `-----` to `h----` .

```
                 String firstSpace = guessedSpaces.substring(0,1);
                String secondSpace = guessedSpaces.substring(2,3);
                String thirdSpace = guessedSpaces.substring(4,5);
                String fourthSpace = guessedSpaces.substring(6,7);

                int one = Integer.parseInt(firstSpace);


                int two = Integer.parseInt(secondSpace);
                int three = Integer.parseInt(thirdSpace);
                int four = Integer.parseInt(fourthSpace);



     (secretWord.charAt(one)==letterGuess)
     (secretWord.charAt(one)==letterGuess)
    (secretWord.charAt(one)==letterGuess)
    (secretWord.charAt(one)==letterGuess)
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis im sorry i meant to say check

Comment: Could it be a case sensitivity issue? E.g. they enter 'a' but secret word has 'A'. Other than that, your code looks ok to me. But it'd be better to see your whole program.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. The secret string, the value you expect from the user, etc... It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Make sure letterGuess is declared as char, not String.

Comment: @aliteralmind sorry sir, i just updated it!

Comment: The question still is very unclear but is the issue that you wanna check all the letters in the word and you are missing an way to loop over the word and compare it to the input you just got?

Comment: @Asthor yes, i need to check the letters in the the actual word for the user-guessed word. but only for the space index's he/she inputs.

Comment: @MikeJ We could really use more code from it to see how you take in the input. Is the index the user put in an int or an string? Or is the `one` in the code part from you an variable?

Comment: @Asthor i just editted to add some more code.

Comment: @MikeJ Is this the all the code you have written or is there more than this? I am sorry but this really doesn't explain your issue with the code, except for the fact that you have secretWord.chartAt(one)==letterGuess) 4 times. Is it not compiling, is the output not as you expect or what is the true issue. Given that these are snippets from your actual code and not the whole code they should work.

Comment: @Asthor do you have an AIM i can message you the full code? and talk plz.

Comment: When you're ready to step up to a Swing based hangman game, check out this [article](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=349).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brief amount of code that is a complete hangman program:

```
static int MAX_MISSES = 5;
static String[] WORDS = { "QUICK", "BROWN", "JUMPS" }; // etc

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String word = WORDS[new Random().nextInt(WORDS.length)], guesses = " ";
    int misses = -1;
    for (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); !word.matches("[" + guesses + "]+") & (misses += word.contains(guesses.substring(0, 1)) ? 0 : 1) <= MAX_MISSES; guesses = in.nextLine().toUpperCase().charAt(0) + guesses)
        System.out.println(word.replaceAll("(?<=.)", " ").replaceAll("[^" + guesses + "]", "_"));
    System.out.println(word + (misses > MAX_MISSES ? " not" : "") + " solved with " + misses + " incorrect guesses");
}
```

Some notes:

- Regex is used to both check for solution and display the current guess status
- `&` is used instead of `&&` in the loop termination to force both sides of the logic to be executed - thus always updating the misses correctly
- Various other tricks have been used to deliberately increase code density

There is no error checking for input. If more than one letter is input by the user, only the first is used. If no letters are input, it will explode. Error checking could be added without adding much more code, but the `for` line would be a whopper - I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Also, there is no checking for erroneously guessing the same letter multiple times. With this code, if you guess a correct letter twice, nothing bad happens, but if you guess a wrong letter twice, it counts as a separate "miss", so you'll burn one of your chances.

Comment: Excellent. I've taken this and made it my own, which I've added as a new answer. It's not better, I just did it for the sake of learning it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22275609/2736496

Comment: I've written a blog post based on your answer: http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/hangman2/

Comment: @aliteralmind I have shaved another line off the code, which actually improves it from a variable scope perspective (the scope of the scanner object `in` is now limited to just the loop). Perhaps you could edit your blog to reflect this (it's more 1337!)

Comment: @aliteralmind another update to blog required: the requirement for spaces in dictionary words has been removed by a simple pre-spacing step in the output. It also makes the final message better (no spaces there). see updated code

Answer (score 1):

*[My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22275609/2736496)*

I had a little too much fun with this.

The main class:

```
public class HangmanWord  {
   private static final char MASK_CHAR = '-';
   private final String word;
   private final char[] maskedWordChars;
   private int totalMatched;
   public HangmanWord(String alphaNum_secretWord)  {
      int wordLen = -1;
      try  {
         wordLen = alphaNum_secretWord.length();
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("alphaNum_secretWord");
      }

      if(wordLen == 0)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("alphaNum_secretWord is non-null, but empty.");
      }

      //default is automatically false
      maskedWordChars = new char[wordLen];
      Arrays.fill(maskedWordChars, MASK_CHAR);
      totalMatched = 0;

      if(!Pattern.compile("^\\w+").matcher(alphaNum_secretWord).matches())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("alphaNum_secretWord (\"" + alphaNum_secretWord + "\") must contain only letters and digits.");
      }
      word = alphaNum_secretWord;
   }
   public int length()  {
      return  maskedWordChars.length;
   }
   public int getTotalMatchedCount()  {
      return  totalMatched;
   }
   public boolean didWin()  {
      return  (getTotalMatchedCount() == length());
   }
```

The main logic function in HangmanWord:

```
   public int getMatchedCountFromGuess(char guessChar, int... idxGuesses)  {
      if(idxGuesses.length == 0)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("idxGuesses.length is zero.");
      }
      int guessedCount = 0;
      for(int idx : idxGuesses)  {
         try  {
            if(maskedWordChars[idx] == MASK_CHAR  &&  word.charAt(idx) == guessChar)  {
               maskedWordChars[idx] = guessChar;
               guessedCount++;
            }
         }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abx)  {
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + idx + " is invalid, given length() is " + length(), abx);
         }
      }
      totalMatched += guessedCount;
      return  guessedCount;
   }
   public String getMasked()  {
      return  (new String(maskedWordChars));
   }
```

And demo usage, which takes advantage of the below `HangmanGuess` class.

Note that this *does not* accept user-input. Hence the above guess class, in which I can store simulated input. There is an array of guess-objects below.

(Testing a significant program such as this with user input is a nightmare. I actually created the user-input code, but deleted by accident. I was going to put it in a separate function, so it could be optionally used, but got distracted before I pasted it back. It is ***so stinking cumbersome*** to enter all this data by hand every time you run it. I just don't get why user-input is required so much in CS education/chosen by newbies, for use in anything but the most trivial programs.)

```
   public static final void main(String[] idx0_alphaNumSecretWord)  {
      HangmanWord hword = null;
      try  {
         hword = new HangmanWord(idx0_alphaNumSecretWord[0]);
      }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abx)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Missing one required parameter: The alpha-numeric secret word.");
      }

      //TESTING ONLY:
         //#=matches in guess
         HangmanGuess[] testGuesses = new HangmanGuess[]{ //012345678901
            new HangmanGuess('t', 2, 3, 4),               //onomatopoeia
            new HangmanGuess('e', 6, 7, 8, 9), //1
            new HangmanGuess('a', 6, 7, 8),
            new HangmanGuess('a', 4),          //1
            new HangmanGuess('o', 0, 3),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('o', 0, 2, 8 ,6), //3
            new HangmanGuess('p', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),  //1
            new HangmanGuess('n', 1),          //1
            new HangmanGuess('t', 4, 5),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('z', 0),
            new HangmanGuess('m', 3, 4),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('i', 10),         //1
            new HangmanGuess('a', 11)          //1
         };
         int testIdx = 0;
```

Main usage-logic:

```
      while(!hword.didWin())  {
         System.out.print("The secret word is: " + hword.getMasked() + ". Guess (char idx idx idx ...): ");

         //LIVE only:  (must create!)
         //  HangmanGuess hguess = getGuessFromUserInput();
         //Testing only...START
            HangmanGuess hguess = testGuesses[testIdx++];
            System.out.print(hguess);
         //Testing only...END

         int matchesThisGuess = hword.getMatchedCountFromGuess(hguess.chr, hguess.idxGuesses);

         System.out.println();

         if(matchesThisGuess == 0)  {
            System.out.println("No characters guessed.");
         }
      }
      System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + hword.getMasked());

   }
}
```

Guess class:

```
class HangmanGuess  {
   public final char chr;
   public final int[] idxGuesses;
   public HangmanGuess(char chr, int... idxGuesses)  {
      this.chr = chr;
      this.idxGuesses = idxGuesses;
   }
   public String toString()  {
      StringBuilder bldr = (new StringBuilder()).append(chr).append(" ");
      for(int i : idxGuesses)  {
         bldr.append(i + " ");
      }
      return  bldr.toString();
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java HangmanWord onomatopoeia
The secret word is: ------------. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): t 2 3 4
No characters guessed.
The secret word is: ------------. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): e 6 7 8 9
The secret word is: ---------e--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): a 6 7 8
No characters guessed.
The secret word is: ---------e--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): a 4
The secret word is: ----a----e--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): o 0 3
The secret word is: o---a----e--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): o 0 2 8 6
The secret word is: o-o-a-o-oe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): p 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
The secret word is: o-o-a-opoe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): n 1
The secret word is: ono-a-opoe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): t 4 5
The secret word is: ono-atopoe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): z 0
No characters guessed.
The secret word is: ono-atopoe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): m 3 4
The secret word is: onomatopoe--. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): i 10
The secret word is: onomatopoei-. Guess (char idx idx idx ...): a 11
SUCCESS: onomatopoeia
```

Full source-code:

```
   import  java.util.Scanner;
   import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java HangmanWord onomatopoeia}</P>
 **/
public class HangmanWord  {
   private static final char MASK_CHAR = '-';
   private final String word;
   private final char[] maskedWordChars;
   private int totalMatched;
   public HangmanWord(String alphaNum_secretWord)  {
      int wordLen = -1;
      try  {
         wordLen = alphaNum_secretWord.length();
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("alphaNum_secretWord");
      }

      if(wordLen == 0)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("alphaNum_secretWord is non-null, but empty.");
      }

      //default is automatically false
      maskedWordChars = new char[wordLen];
      Arrays.fill(maskedWordChars, MASK_CHAR);
      totalMatched = 0;

      if(!Pattern.compile("^\\w+").matcher(alphaNum_secretWord).matches())  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("alphaNum_secretWord (\"" + alphaNum_secretWord + "\") must contain only letters and digits.");
      }
      word = alphaNum_secretWord;
   }
   public int length()  {
      return  maskedWordChars.length;
   }
   public int getTotalMatchedCount()  {
      return  totalMatched;
   }
   public boolean didWin()  {
      return  (getTotalMatchedCount() == length());
   }
   public int getMatchedCountFromGuess(char guessChar, int... idxGuesses)  {
      if(idxGuesses.length == 0)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("idxGuesses.length is zero.");
      }
      int guessedCount = 0;
      for(int idx : idxGuesses)  {
         try  {
            if(maskedWordChars[idx] == MASK_CHAR  &&  word.charAt(idx) == guessChar)  {
               maskedWordChars[idx] = guessChar;
               guessedCount++;
            }
         }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abx)  {
            throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + idx + " is invalid, given length() is " + length(), abx);
         }
      }
      totalMatched += guessedCount;
      return  guessedCount;
   }
   public String getMasked()  {
      return  (new String(maskedWordChars));
   }

   public static final void main(String[] idx0_alphaNumSecretWord)  {
      HangmanWord hword = null;
      try  {
         hword = new HangmanWord(idx0_alphaNumSecretWord[0]);
      }  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException abx)  {
         throw  new IllegalArgumentException("Missing one required parameter: The alpha-numeric secret word.");
      }

      //TESTING only
         //#=matches in guess
         HangmanGuess[] testGuesses = new HangmanGuess[]{ //012345678901
            new HangmanGuess('t', 2, 3, 4),               //onomatopoeia
            new HangmanGuess('e', 6, 7, 8, 9), //1
            new HangmanGuess('a', 6, 7, 8),
            new HangmanGuess('a', 4),          //1
            new HangmanGuess('o', 0, 3),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('o', 0, 2, 8 ,6), //3
            new HangmanGuess('p', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11),  //1
            new HangmanGuess('n', 1),          //1
            new HangmanGuess('t', 4, 5),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('z', 0),
            new HangmanGuess('m', 3, 4),       //1
            new HangmanGuess('i', 10),         //1
            new HangmanGuess('a', 11)          //1
         };
         int testIdx = 0;

      while(!hword.didWin())  {
         System.out.print("The secret word is: " + hword.getMasked() + ". Guess (char idx idx idx ...): ");

         //LIVE only:  (must create!)
         //  HangmanGuess hguess = getGuessFromUserInput();
         //Testing only...START
            HangmanGuess hguess = testGuesses[testIdx++];
            System.out.print(hguess);
         //Testing only...END

         int matchesThisGuess = hword.getMatchedCountFromGuess(hguess.chr, hguess.idxGuesses);

         System.out.println();

         if(matchesThisGuess == 0)  {
            System.out.println("No characters guessed.");
         }
      }
      System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + hword.getMasked());

   }
}
class HangmanGuess  {
   public final char chr;
   public final int[] idxGuesses;
   public HangmanGuess(char chr, int... idxGuesses)  {
      this.chr = chr;
      this.idxGuesses = idxGuesses;
   }
   public String toString()  {
      StringBuilder bldr = (new StringBuilder()).append(chr).append(" ");
      for(int i : idxGuesses)  {
         bldr.append(i + " ");
      }
      return  bldr.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you can do the whole thing in a just a few lines of code, and the main logic in two lines

Comment: @Bohemian: I hope you share some hints on what you're talking about. I would love the education.

Comment: OK. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263843/trying-to-implement-text-based-hangman-game-in-java/22269413#22269413) for a high density solution. As promised, the main loop is two lines (one line for the loop control, one to output the current guess status) :)

Answer (score 1):

*[My other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22264791/2736496)*

I've taken [Bohemian's dense-and-great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/2736496), and made it my own. It's not better, I did it only for the sake of learning it. While it doesn't fulfill the OP's specifications, the specifications are very different than normal hangman (you have to explicitly specify indexes at which the guessed-letter applies to). This application is much closer to normal Hangman rules.

The major differences from Bohemian's code are

- It's a `do-while`, instead of a `for` loop.
- It only keeps unique characters, and compares against a separate `currCharGuessAsStr`, instead of the first character in `allGuessCharsStr`.
- It notifies the user of bad input (no characters) instead of crashing, and requires input to be a single letter.
- It displays state at each step.

Pre loop:

```
public class Hangman  {
   static int MAX_BAD_GUESSES = 10;
   static String[] WORDS = { "QUICK", "BROWN", "JUMPS" }; // etc

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String word = WORDS[new Random().nextInt(WORDS.length)];
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int badGuessCount = 0;
      String guessInput = null;

      //Could be character key, but a ONE-CHARACTER STRING instead
      //To avoid having to translate back and forth between string
      //and char.
      Map<String,Object> unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap = new TreeMap<String,Object>();

      //Must be initialized to the empty string. Initializing to null
      //Will result in the literal string "null" being added to it.
      String allGuessCharsStr = "";
      String currCharGuessAsStr = " ";
```

The loop:

```
      do  {

         System.out.print(getMasked(word, allGuessCharsStr) + " Guess a character [Bad guesses: " + badGuessCount + " of " + MAX_BAD_GUESSES + "]: ");

         guessInput = in.nextLine();

         if(guessInput != null)  {  //null on first iteration only
            if(!guessInput.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$"))  {
               System.out.println("Bad input. Must a single letter.");
               badGuessCount++;

            }  else  {
               //Definitely valid input, and exactly one character
               currCharGuessAsStr = guessInput.toUpperCase();

               if(unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap.containsKey(currCharGuessAsStr))  {
                  //Trim to eliminate initialization space
                  System.out.println("Already guessed that letter. All guesses: " + allGuessCharsStr.trim());

               }  else  {
                  unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap.put(currCharGuessAsStr, null);

                  //Prepend just-guessed character and sort it.
                  allGuessCharsStr += currCharGuessAsStr;
                  char[] allGuessedChars = allGuessCharsStr.toCharArray();
                  Arrays.sort(allGuessedChars);
                  allGuessCharsStr = new String(allGuessedChars);
               }

               if(!word.contains(currCharGuessAsStr))  {
                  badGuessCount++;
               }
            }
         }

      }  while(!word.matches("[" + allGuessCharsStr + "]+")  &&
                  badGuessCount <= MAX_BAD_GUESSES);
```

Post-loop, and `getMasked(s,s)` function:

```
      System.out.println(getMasked(word, allGuessCharsStr));

      System.out.println(word + (badGuessCount > MAX_BAD_GUESSES ? " not" : "") + " solved with " + badGuessCount + " incorrect guesses (max allowed=" + MAX_BAD_GUESSES + ").");
   }

   /**
      @param  all_guessesStrESIfNone  May not be null. If empty, no guesses have been made yet.
      @exception  PatternSyntaxException  If all_guessCharsStr is empty.
    **/
   private static final String getMasked(String secret_word, String all_guessesStrESIfNone)  {
      try  {
         if(all_guessesStrESIfNone.length() == 0)  {
            all_guessesStrESIfNone = " ";   //Any non-letter will suffice
         }
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("all_guessesStrESIfNone");
      }

      //Mask all not-yet-guessed characters with an underscore.
      secret_word = secret_word.replaceAll("[^" + all_guessesStrESIfNone + "]", "_");

      //Insert a space between every character (trim eliminates the final).
      return  secret_word.replaceAll("(.)", "$1 ").trim();
   }
}
```

Solved output:

```
[C:\java_code]java Hangman
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 0 of 10]: a
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 1 of 10]: b
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 2 of 10]: c
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 3 of 10]: d
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 4 of 10]: e
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 5 of 10]: f
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 6 of 10]: j
J _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 6 of 10]: q
J _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 7 of 10]: m
J _ M _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 7 of 10]: p
J _ M P _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 7 of 10]: u
J U M P _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 7 of 10]: s
J U M P S
JUMPS solved with 7 incorrect guesses (max allowed=10).
```

Unsolved output:

```
[C:\java_code]java Hangman
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 0 of 10]: a
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 1 of 10]: b
_ _ _ _ _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 2 of 10]: c
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 2 of 10]: d
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 3 of 10]: e
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 4 of 10]: f
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 5 of 10]: j
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 6 of 10]: e
Already guessed that letter. All guesses: ABCDEFJ
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 7 of 10]:
Bad input. Must a single letter.
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 8 of 10]: tt
Bad input. Must a single letter.
_ _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 9 of 10]: q
Q _ _ C _ Guess a character [Bad guesses: 9 of 10]: k
Q _ _ C K Guess a character [Bad guesses: 9 of 10]: l
Q _ _ C K Guess a character [Bad guesses: 10 of 10]: z
Q _ _ C K
QUICK not solved with 11 incorrect guesses (max allowed=10).
```

Full code:

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
   import  java.util.Map;
   import  java.util.TreeMap;
   import  java.util.Random;
   import  java.util.Scanner;
/**
   <P>{@code java Hangman}</P>
 **/
public class Hangman  {
   static int MAX_BAD_GUESSES = 10;
   static String[] WORDS = { "QUICK", "BROWN", "JUMPS" }; // etc

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String word = WORDS[new Random().nextInt(WORDS.length)];
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int badGuessCount = 0;
      String guessInput = null;

      //Could be character key, but a ONE-CHARACTER STRING instead
      //To avoid having to translate back and forth between string
      //and char.
      Map<String,Object> unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap = new TreeMap<String,Object>();

      //Must be initialized to the empty string. Initializing to null
      //Will result in the literal string "null" being added to it.
      String allGuessCharsStr = "";
      String currCharGuessAsStr = " ";

      do  {

         System.out.print(getMasked(word, allGuessCharsStr) + " Guess a character [Bad guesses: " + badGuessCount + " of " + MAX_BAD_GUESSES + "]: ");

         guessInput = in.nextLine();

         if(guessInput != null)  {  //null on first iteration only
            if(!guessInput.matches("^[a-zA-Z]$"))  {
               System.out.println("Bad input. Must a single letter.");
               badGuessCount++;

            }  else  {
               //Definitely valid input, and exactly one character
               currCharGuessAsStr = guessInput.toUpperCase();

               if(unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap.containsKey(currCharGuessAsStr))  {
                  //Trim to eliminate initialization space
                  System.out.println("Already guessed that letter. All guesses: " + allGuessCharsStr.trim());

               }  else  {
                  unqGuessedCharsAsStrMap.put(currCharGuessAsStr, null);

                  //Prepend just-guessed character and sort it.
                  allGuessCharsStr += currCharGuessAsStr;
                  char[] allGuessedChars = allGuessCharsStr.toCharArray();
                  Arrays.sort(allGuessedChars);
                  allGuessCharsStr = new String(allGuessedChars);
               }

               if(!word.contains(currCharGuessAsStr))  {
                  badGuessCount++;
               }
            }
         }

      }  while(!word.matches("[" + allGuessCharsStr + "]+")  &&
                  badGuessCount <= MAX_BAD_GUESSES);

      System.out.println(getMasked(word, allGuessCharsStr));

      System.out.println(word + (badGuessCount > MAX_BAD_GUESSES ? " not" : "") + " solved with " + badGuessCount + " incorrect guesses (max allowed=" + MAX_BAD_GUESSES + ").");
   }

   /**
      @param  all_guessesStrESIfNone  May not be null. If empty, no guesses have been made yet.
      @exception  PatternSyntaxException  If all_guessCharsStr is empty.
    **/
   private static final String getMasked(String secret_word, String all_guessesStrESIfNone)  {
      try  {
         if(all_guessesStrESIfNone.length() == 0)  {
            all_guessesStrESIfNone = " ";   //Any non-letter will suffice
         }
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("all_guessesStrESIfNone");
      }

      //Mask all not-yet-guessed characters with an underscore.
      secret_word = secret_word.replaceAll("[^" + all_guessesStrESIfNone + "]", "_");

      //Insert a space between every character (trim eliminates the final).
      return  secret_word.replaceAll("(.)", "$1 ").trim();
   }
}
```

Comment: This is now a(nother) blog post: http://aliteralmind.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/hangman2

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us how did it went wrong.

I'm guessing you're trying to write a 'hangman' program. I would make a wild guess that you forgot index returned by charAt() start from zero.

Comment: how do i add this? sorry im a beginner, not quite sure