# I want to multiply a string in java for hangman

Tags: java

I want to multiply an underscore for making the dash in Hangman.

```
    String dash = random_word.length() * " __ ";
```

where random_word is a random word picked from an array.

Comment: For comparison, here's an [entire hangman program done in 4 lines of java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/256196) (which makes this question moot).

Answer (score 3):

maybe you want something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<random_word.length();i++){
    sb.append(" __ ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString);
```

StringBuilder will allow you to optimize your performance..

Comment: Well there is several ways to do this same first to replace

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace all to do this.

```
String dash = random_word.replaceAll("."," __ ");
```

I have though a multiply function for strings would be good but it is not 
supported in any language I have come across.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop:

```
String my_string = " __ ";
String result = ""
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < random_word.length(); x++) result += my_string;
```

I *think* I understand your question...

Comment: Its alright guys. I found it. I used a loop.

    String dash_raw = " __ ";
     
     String dash = "";
     
     for(int i = 0; i < rand_word_length; ++i){
         dash += dash_raw;
     }
     
Anyway thanks for the great help! Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there is several ways to do this same first to replace

```
String dash = random_word.replaceAll("."," __ ");
```

other way to use StringBuffer and u can apped at last.
and even u can use stringBuilder.

```
    String no1 = "Gettingerror but may be not.";
        String mul = "__";

        System.out.println(no1.replace(".", mul));

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < no1.length(); i++) {
            builder.append(no1.charAt(i));
            if (i==no1.length()-1) {
                builder.append(mul);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

and very simple way and best way is to use concet that is given default method from string class

```
string.concat(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [StringUtuils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) api.

It contains methods to help you in padding strings such as:
[StringUtils.leftPad()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and [StringUtils.rightPad()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#rightPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)