# Showing words in Hangman

Tags: java, oop

I have a class called Letter which has two parameters:

```
Letter(char chr, boolean Guessed)
```

When I run my main method Hangman problem, if the guessed word is correct, I want to be able to change the value of the boolean Guessed into true.
I have a getter and a setter for this.

In my hangman game, I want to be able to print the words that were guessed in a proper location.

Example: If word is java, then if a person guesses 'a', I want the program to print
_ a _ a.

I'm not sure how I would go about to doing so. I know how to switch the Boolean of the variable but I'm not sure how I would update the printing portion.

Would I have a create a new string so that it saves the previous values that have been updated?

```
private boolean isGuessRight(char chr){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++){
            if (word.charAt(i) == chr && Letter.getRevealed() == false){
                Letter.reveal();
                return true;
            }
            else if (word.charAt(i) == chr && Letter.getRevealed()){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm also having a hard time figuring it out why java tells me that I cannot call the method Letter.reveal(). reveal() is a non-static method from the subclass letter and I feel like I shouldn't have any problems doing so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although it is a non-static method, but you are invoking it statically. You should get the letter instance from word and then invoke the method on the same

Comment: Static methods belong to a class, and are called using, in your example `Letter.reveal()`. If you are referencing to one of the letters, and your method `isGuessRight` is in the `Letter` class, you should use `this.getRevealed()` and `this.reveal()`.

Comment: @dinomario10 my method isGuessRight is not in the Letter class.. should I initialize the class Letter in my isGuessRight method then?

Comment: @rahulroc Letter l = new letter('a', false) would something like this work?

Comment: Exactly. Letter A = new Letter('A', false). Created an answer to exemplify it.

Comment: For your interest, here is a [complete java implementation of hangman in 5 lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/256196). It doesn't use any classes. Instead it solves that problem by using regex to replace un-guessed letters with an underscore.

Comment: Thing is, you're really dealing with data, not objects. The set of letters that has been guessed can be represented by a set of characters. It doesn't need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Letter {
 char c;
boolean isRevealed;

//... getters and setters
}

Letter[] word = new Letter[MAX_WORD_LENGTH]; 

private boolean isGuessRight(char chr){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length ; i++){
            if (word[i].getChar() == chr && word[i].getRevealed() == false){
                word[i].reveal();
                return true;
            }
            else if (word[i] == chr && word[i].getRevealed()){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```