# Changing the value inside an Array List?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

```
for(int i = 0; i <= gameWord.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(guessLetter.charAt(0) == (gameWord.charAt(i)))
        {
            hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);
        }
        else if(guessLetter.charAt(0) != (gameWord.charAt(i)))
        {
            System.out.print("_" + " ");
        }
    }
```

I am making a hangman game and I have created an array list called hideword. Hideword prints an underscore for each letter that is in the word used for the game. I am trying to right a method that will swap the underscore with a letter the user guesses. However this code

```
hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);
```

Doesn't work. It gives me "array required, but java.util.ArrayList found

Anyone help?

Comment: As a curiosity, here's an [implementation of hangman in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/256196) that uses very few lines.

Answer (score 3):

Then, hideword must be an arraylist. Use `hideword.set(index, character)` for assignment instead of accessing it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` is not an array, it's a `List` implementation (however, its implementation is *backed* by an array - hence the name).

Declare `hideword` as an array of `char`:

```
private char[] hideword;
```

and initialize it before use:

```
hideword = new char[gameword.length];
```

---

You code, without changing its basic intention, can be simplified greatly:

- There's no need to subtract `1` from the length, just change the comparison operator
- There's no need to have your `if` in the `else` - we already *know* it's not equal because we're in the `else` block
- Rather than do useless print, assign an underscore to the array slot
- Do one print at the end

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameWord.length(); i++) {
    if (guessLetter.charAt(0) == (gameWord.charAt(i))) {
        hideword[i] = guessLetter.charAt(0);
    } else {
        hideword[i] = '_';
    }
}
// print hideword
```

You code would be simpler still if `hideword` didn't exist and you simply `System.out.print()` each character as you test it instead.

Comment: Are you sure I can use char for the array list? I can't print anything if I'm using it

Comment: @ian it's not an array list!!! It's an array. One way to print: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("\\W", ""));`