# Can not find out why my output is printing 2 times and how swap chars in StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am using a StringBuilder and appending it with * for each letter of the word to be guessed. Then when the user guesses a letter/char correct the StringBuilder should be changing the char at a certain index from * to the guessed letter/char. Then print the new StringBuilder to show the correct letter like this (ho * s *). If the guess is wrong then just print the StringBuilder and say wrong guess.

I am trying to figure out why this is not working properly. I am getting output like: (minus the / it wouldn't post just the *)

HANGMAN

Try and guess the word, you have 9 attempts:

/***************

Guess a letter: g

/*************************

Guess a letter: p

p****p****p****p****p****

Guess a letter

It is also printing the word more than once and I am not sure why.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Hangman {
static String[] words = {"house", "show", "garage", "computer", "programming", "porch", "dog"};
static char[] correct = new char[26];
static char[] wrong = new char[26];
static char guess;
static Random generator = new Random();
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static String word;
static int attempts = 0;
static StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 public static void main(String[] args){

    word = words[generator.nextInt(words.length)];
    System.out.print("HANGMAN\nTry and guess the word, you have 9 attempts: \n");
    printAstrick();

    while(attempts <= 9){
        System.out.print("\nGuess a letter: ");
        guess = input.next().charAt(0);
        findMatch(guess);

    }    
    if(attempts == 9){
        System.out.println("Your attempts are up");
        }
}

public static void findMatch(char c){
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
            if(word.charAt(i) == c){
                correct[i] = c;
                sb.setCharAt(i, c);
                System.out.print(sb.toString());

            }
            else if(word.charAt(i) != c){
                wrong[i] = c;
                sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
                System.out.print(sb.toString());

            }

        }
    attempts++;
}

public static void printAstrick(){
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        sb.append("*");
        System.out.print(sb.toString());
    }

 }
```

Comment: FYI [How to implement hangman in java using only 5 lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22269413/256196)

Comment: it's not "good" code, because it's not easily readable; it's more a curiosity, like code golf. You may be able to simplify certain parts of your code like the part you're asking about, which in my version starts with the complete word and replaces *unguessed* letters with a star (simple), rather than your code which adds in the known letters (complicated).

Comment: I understand. I just want to know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting any correct guesses with this line:

```
sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
```

in your `findMatch` method so you should remove it.

Also, your print statements are in `for` loops so each word is printed out *n* times. Fix this by moving your calls to `System.out.print(sb.toString())` outside of the `for` loops.

This leaves you with:

```
public static void findMatch(char c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (word.charAt(i) == c) {
            correct[i] = c;
            sb.setCharAt(i, c);
        } else if (word.charAt(i) != c) {
            wrong[i] = c;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
    attempts++;
}

public static void printAstrick() {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        sb.append("*");
    }
    System.out.print(sb.toString());
}
```