# Java hangman replacing Underscore with user input

Tags: java, oop

for my basic java oop class assignment using basic getter/setter method

i'm using NetBean IDE

```java
public MainFrame() {
    initComponents();
    hangman hangman=new hangman();
    hangman.setWord(Word.wordArray);
    jLabel1.setText(hangman.getWord());
    jLabel2.setText(jLabel1.getText().replaceAll(".", " _ "));
}

private void jTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(jLabel2.getText());
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        hangman hangman=new hangman();
        hangman.setInput(jText.getText().charAt(0));
        jText.setText("");
        for(int j=0; j<jLabel1.getText().length(); j++){
            if(jLabel1.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(j)==hangman.getInput()){
                if(jLabel1.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(j)==hangman.getInput()){
                    builder.setCharAt(j, hangman.getInput());
                    jLabel2.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the getInput show up fine but underscore are still there.

code are incomplete, i'm still trying a lot of function and method and i'm posting this for some insight from you guys in the mean time.

thank you in advances

Comment: best to debug this sort of thing *outside* of the GUI, to allow you to clean up and simplify the code that does the actual text changing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263843/trying-to-implement-text-based-hangman-game-in-java/22269413#22269413

Answer (score 0):

You're using the *wrong* StringBuilder method. You don't want to use `setCharAt(...)` but rather, the `.replace​(int start, int end, String str)` method, here perhaps:

```
builder.replace(j, j+1, stringToInsert);
```

---

As I noted in my comment above, best to debug and enhance your code in isolation from the GUI (unless it is a GUI-specific problem). Here you want to create a class, perhaps `HangmanModel` that holds the String, that holds the current char guesses, and that will give you a String with dashes and with letters as the guesses progress.

---

Side issue regarding:

```
 hangman hangman=new hangman();
```

You will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

So best to change the *class* name to `Hangman`, and then change the above line to:

```
 Hangman hangman = new Hangman();
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the first part of your answer. Why is setCharAt() the wrong approach? I'm asking because I genuinely find it surprising that you'd think this.